# SQL query - How to check that result is first or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query in PostgreSQL shows meetings in some period between :start_date and :end_date.

The problem is with "ktore" column, which show that meeting was first or not. I used "inner join" to add subquery which counts my meetings in company, and if *count > 1*, then write "next", else - "first". But it shows correct result only for last meeting date. Let me show you one example:

In Company1 was two meetings - meeting 1 on 2017-09-02 and meeting 2 on 2017-09-05.

If I choose *:start date* to 2017-09-01 and *:end_date* to 2017-09-06, then my query shows:

```
id   company_name  audit_date  nip      ktore
...
234  Company1      2017-09-02  1234567  NEXT
...
287  Company1      2017-09-05  1234567  NEXT
```

But I want this:

```
id   company_name  audit_date  nip      ktore
...
234  Company1      2017-09-02  1234567  FIRST
...
287  Company1      2017-09-05  1234567  NEXT
```

So what I should do in my query?

```
select a.id, a.company_name, to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi') audit_date, companys.nip, 
    case
        when b.costam > 1 then 'NEXT'
        else 'FIRST'
    end ktore
from companys, meetings a
    inner join (select company_id, count(1) costam from meetings where status !='CANCELED' and status !='SUSPENDED' 
        and to_char(audit_dc,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :end_date group by company_id) b on a.company_id = b.company_id
where to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')>= :start_date 
and to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :end_date and companys.id = a.company_id
```

I think it will be good to write something like "if in company exists meeting with earlier date, then "NEXT", else "FIRST" but I don't know how do it in code.

Thank you in advance,
Mateusz

Comment: Please, don't use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, always explicitly list out your joins.  You especially shouldn't _mix_ them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query it will work. My logic is that from subquery I'm taking minimum of audit_date and then comparing with main table audit date if matches then it will give FIRST else NEXT,  If there are 3 different dates for a companyId then it will give FIRST for min date and NEXT for remaining dates

```
select a.id, a.company_name, to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi') audit_date, companys.nip, 
    case
        when b.costam >1 and min_audit_date=a.audit_date then 'FIRST'
        else 'NEXT'
    end ktore
from companys, meetings a
    inner join (select company_id, count(1) costam,min(audit_date) min_audit_date,max(audit_date) max_audit_date from meetings where status !='CANCELED' and status !='SUSPENDED' 
        and to_char(audit_dc,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :end_date group by company_id) b on a.company_id = b.company_id
where to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')>= :start_date 
and to_char(a.audit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')<= :end_date and companys.id = a.company_id
```

You can change the logic if your logic is reverse of what I did above by using 
 max_audit_date

Comment: ... you could at least clean up the query a bit more while you're at it.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Actually I answered it from my mobile,  so I just gave my logic to implement the OP question

Comment: Perfect idea with min(audit_date)! I deleted count function completely and now it's working well (if b.costam >1 will be still here, there will be a problem with companies, where are only one meeting).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing will work, but the more idiomatic way to do it is by using what's known as [Windowing Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html), probably with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT Meetings.id, Meetings.company_name, 
       TO_CHAR(Meetings.audit_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi') AS audit_date, 
       Companys.nip, 
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Meetings.company_id 
                                   ORDER BY Meetings.audit_date) = 1 
            THEN 'FIRST'
            ELSE 'NEXT'
       END AS ktore
FROM Meetings
JOIN Companys
  ON Companys.id = Meetings.company_id
WHERE Meetings.status NOT IN ('CANCELED', 'SUSPENDED')
      AND Meetings.audit_date >= TIMESTAMP :startDate
      AND Meetings.audit_date < TIMESTAMP :endDate
ORDER BY Meetings.company_id, Meetings.audit_date
```

---

You'll noticed there's been a number of things changed in your query.  And I have some other thoughts.

- `Meetings.company_name` - I have a very difficult time believing that column is in that table, it's more probably that it should be `Companys.company_name`.
- It's `Companies`, but there's a number of debates about whether or not table names should be singular, not plural.
- Your original query counted all meetings before a certain point, regardless of the query window, however my current version returns `'FIRST'` for the first meeting in the window, which might not be the same thing.  It's unclear which you actually wanted.
- For dates and times [always query them with an exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  It's just plain easier.  Plus, the original version of your query would ignore indices, and would make your query run slower.
- Additionally, for date times, you must be very careful of timezones.  It's unclear if that's something to be concerned about here, though.

Comment: I tried query based on your idea and it works almost pefectly, but in my case I want to show all meetings in company - also "canceled" and "suspended" but only meetings without these statuses can be counted as "first" or "next". But I'm sure that I will use your idea with other queries in the future. Thank you for advice.